# В игре конвея Жизнь условия работают неправильно

Tags: javascript

Проверял на сайте игры[Игра](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) и там совсем по-другому идет жизнь, у меня где-то закралась ошибка.При такой расстоновке клетки должны менять положение с вертикального на горизонтальное, а у меня жизнь [Моя игра](https://jsfiddle.net/kpgjzbht/2/)  идет полным ходом[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WsQK.png)[[image: Клетки должны меняться в гориз положение и вертикальное]]

```js
class ConfigField {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.array = [];
    let timer;
    this.timer = timer;
    this.generatePlayingField();
    this.canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.clickCanvasEvent(e);
    });
    this.drawGrid();
    document.getElementById('start')
      .addEventListener('click', () => this.startLife());
    document.getElementById('stop')
      .addEventListener('click', () => this.stopLife());

  }

  generatePlayingField() {
    const n = 50, m = 50;
    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      this.array[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        this.array[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  clickCanvasEvent(event) {
    let x = event.offsetX;
    let y = event.offsetY;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
    y = Math.floor(y / 10);
    this.array[x][y] = 1;
    console.log(this.array);
    this.drawField();
  }

  drawGrid() {
    for (let x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
      this.context.moveTo(x, 0);
      this.context.lineTo(x, 500);
    }

    for (let y = 0.5; y < 500; y += 10) {
      this.context.moveTo(0, y);
      this.context.lineTo(500, y);
    }
    this.context.strokeStyle = '#888';
    this.context.stroke();
  }

  drawField() {
    this.context.clearRect(
      0, 0, 500, 500,
    );
    this.drawGrid();
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        if (this.array[i][j] == 1) {
          this.context.fillStyle = 'green';
          this.context.fillRect(
            i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  startLife() {
    // start gameOfLife
    const array2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      array2[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        let neighbors = 0;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;// up
        if (this.array[i][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;// right
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;// bottom
        if (this.array[i][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;// left
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        // rules
        if (neighbors < 2) {
          array2[i][j] = 0;
        } else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3) {
          array2[i][j] = 1;
        } else if (neighbors > 3) {
          array2[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    this.array = array2;
    this.drawField();
    let count = 0;
    count++;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.startLife.bind(this), 300);
  }

  stopLife() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  static fpm(i) {
    if (i == 0) return 50;
    else return i;
  }

  static fpp(i) {
    if (i == 49) return -1;
    else return i;
  }
}

const test = new ConfigField();
console.log(test);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  #canvas {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <div id="count"></div>
      <button id="start">Start</button>
      <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Опишите, в чем отличие

Comment: написал и сделал скрин

Comment: У Вас клетка рождается, если есть 2 или 3 живых соседа (`else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3) {array2[i][j] = 1;}`), а в классической игре "Жизнь" - только если ровно 3.

Comment: тогда все клетки умирают очень быстро, такого быть не должно же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох уже эта "Жизнь". Быстро умирают, потому что неправильное условие:

```
else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3)
```

На самом деле это два условия:

```
else if ((this.array[i][j] === 1) && (neighbors === 2))  { // клетка жива, два соседа, остается жива
     array2[i][j] = 1;
} else if (neighbors === 3)  { // три соседа - становится живой/остается жива
     array2[i][j] = 1;
}
```

*PS. На будущее: "условия работают неправильно" - такого в информатике нет.  Условия **всегда** работают правильно. А если кажется, что неправильно, то это означает только одно - само условие неправильное.*

Comment: теперь вообще какой-то ад на поле:)

Comment: Отличная иллюстрация для моего PS ;) Там ``&&`` конечно же вместо ``||``. Исправил. И скобки добавил для удобства чтения.